# The greyed-out file might have an impact on the program

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a while, I have noticed that my *config.js* file is grey, compared to most other files in the editor. I also have an issue where, other than `text/html` and `image/x-icon`, the MIME type of static assets cannot be established. I am wondering whether the two issues are related.

[image]

Aside from setting up the server, the `config` file serves a base Url along with NodeJS `global` variables to be interpolated into placeholders in the HTML document. While I don't see any reason for there to be an associated problem, I am perplexed why the file is grey and not the same colour as the other `.js` files.

I have tried to find information on the problem, but I cannot describe the problem well enough to find answers to the issue browser searching. I have tried to find a VSCode forum, but there isn't one where I could make enquiry, even if I were able to articulate my problem.

If anyone has answer to why the file is greyed-out I would appreciate it.

Comment: It might be because the file wasn't edited and git colors edited, deleted, and added files. If you are using a git repository.

Comment: your MIME issue is a webserver issue, has nothing to do with VSC, `config.js` is not changed compared to the HEAD of the repo

Comment: You almost got it right, but to be exact the `config.js` file is being ignored and not tracked at all by git. @Den you can confirm it by checking out content of `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Apologies for late response; I've been busy. @Dolimight: & @rioV8: I will check. @Grekkq: I will check my .gitignore; if it is the case that I have entered the `config` file, should I remove it? I didn't consider it to be necessary to track changes to the `config.js` file, but I may be wrong?

Comment: In my`.gitignore` file, I have entered `.env`, relating to API keys, which I don't have at the moment. However, when I make an edit to `config.js`, the auto-save briefly highlights the file and then it goes back to being dull grey. I shall accept that there isn't a problem with the file in its visible state, but I feel a little uneasy about it because I am not clear about what is actually occurring. Nonetheless, thank you all for your assistance.